# Angular Karma Test Issue

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I am writing a Karma test for my service and here is a code snippet:

```
  it('token interceptor should have been called', fakeAsync(() => {
    spy = spyOn(jwtService, 'intercept');
    jwtService.getJwt().subscribe(response => {
    // These statements are not called
    expect(response).toBeTruthy();
    expect(response).toEqual('blablablabla');
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1000);
  });
  const httpRequest = httpMock.expectOne(configService.getLoginServiceUrl() + '/pc/v1/whoami');
  expect(httpRequest.request.headers.has('Authorization')).toEqual(true);

  // This statement always return error that spy called 0 times
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
 }));
```

The issue I am facing is that the expected checks inside my subscriber are never evaluated, for example,
 this statement
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1000);

should fail because the spied on method is called only once,but there is no error. 
Secondly, if I put these checks outside the subscribe block, they always fail. How can I fix these issues?

Below is the code for the getJWT method which makes an http request and returns the result as an Observer:

```
  getJwt(): Observable<string> {

    const url = this.configservice.getLoginServiceUrl() + '/pc/v1/whoami';
    return this.http.get(url).pipe(
    map(() => {
    if (JwtService.jwt != null ) {
    return JwtService.jwt.toString();
    }
    }));

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Check that the subscription completes succesfully

```
  it('token interceptor should have been called', fakeAsync(() => {
    spy = spyOn(jwtService, 'intercept');
    jwtService.getJwt().subscribe(response => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    // These statements are not called
    expect(response).toBeTruthy();
    expect(response).toEqual('blablablabla');
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1000);
  }, (error) => { console.log(error)});
```

## Check that you are not logging the error

The added error clause in the example is doing just that

## Make sure the getJwt is a spy and returns a subscribable object.

You can create those using the of operator.

## Use tick to simulate the passage of time after the subscription

https://angular.io/api/core/testing/tick

## Share more information

Especially the part were you mock the response of the getJwt() function.

Comment: Please share also the mocks of http and config service